# Maven executing goals concurrently

Tags: maven

How can I execute several Maven goals on the same project concurrently? My exact scenario is after having installed sevaral gigabytes of artifacts locally I would start deployment to Nexus, but since it will take a while, I would also like to start executing additional goals with exec plugin - the two tasks are not generally dependent on one another, but they add up to a significant time waste.

I was hoping Maven has any sort of idiom for that, but other solutions are welcome. I would need a way to fail the build if any of the tasks fails (bonus points for a solution that would notify the other goal to fail fast).

Comment: You shouldn't use `mvn install` and afterwards `mvn deploy` simply use `mvn deploy` that do all you need. Goals can't be executed in parallel... the question is what is really the problem? The build can be parallelized via `mvn -T 3 deploy` ... what kind of supplemental task are you talking about? Either they are needed for build or just not ... You should explain more detail what you are doing and why...

Comment: The supplemental tasks in question are in fact setup for integration test - they generate test data, populate databases, etc. Because they depend on installed artifacts, but are themselves not required to be stored in nexus, it is more time efficient to locally build required artifacts and only then do `mvn deploy` for only some. I was hoping to parallelize the nexus upload and data genertion steps as both take few minutes to complete,

Comment: If there is something for a integration tests I recommend to make a separate module which handles that ..which needs a dependency to the used artifacts which will automatically handle the order in the build ... But if you have data for IT's why is it not needed on Nexus? When/Where do you run IT's ? Not as part of a CI / Build? Really gigabytes of artifacts? What is getting that size? Code?